# Executing bash scripts simultaneously

Tags: bash, shell-script

I run several bash scripts in separate terminal windows (tabs). I want to mix them to run in the same window and provide mix outputs. I just need to initiate all scripts independently in the same window.

The common solution is to use `&` as

```
./script1 &
./script2 &
./script3
```

BUT I don't want to send the scripts to work in the background since I do not have control over them in the terminal. For example, I cannot terminate this script by `Ctrl+C`, as the background processes will not be killed by `Ctrl+C`.

Comment: I think you need to read `LESS='+/^JOB CONTROL' man bash`.  In particular, you can run the `jobs` builtin to see a list of current jobs, and can kill them using jobspecs such as `kill %2` and so forth.

Comment: Would something like GNU parallel be useful?

Comment: Read up on the `pkill` man page: that will make it easier to send an INT signal to the right process.

Comment: If you run all three and press ctrl+c which one do you want to end?

Comment: @Jesse_b I want to end all, like it is a single script.

Answer (score 5):

You can run your scripts in tmux or screen in almost any number of background processes. Those processes can be accessed in any time you want.

See [tmux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/tmux) or [GNU screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/)

Answer (score 3):

You could write a wrapper script around them that sends them all to the background and then traps ctrl+c:

```
#!/bin/bash

trap ctrl_c INT

scripts=( ./script1.sh ./script2.sh ./script3.sh )

ctrl_c () {
    printf 'Found [%i] PIDs running\n' "${#pids[@]}"
    for pid in "${pids[@]}"; do
        printf 'Killing PID: %i\n' "$pid"
        kill "$pid"
    done
}

for script in "${scripts[@]}"; do
    "$script" &
    pids+=($!)
done

for pid in "${pids[@]}"; do
    wait "$pid"
done
```

---

So if you press ctrl+c it will kill all the pids that have been previously captured:

```
$ cat ./script{1..3}.sh
#!/bin/bash

sleep 30; echo foo
#!/bin/bash

sleep 30; echo bar
#!/bin/bash

sleep 30; echo baz

$ ./script4.sh
^CFound [3] PIDs running
Killing PID: 48971
Killing PID: 48972
Killing PID: 48973
./script4.sh: line 21: 48971 Terminated: 15          "$script"
./script4.sh: line 21: 48972 Terminated: 15          "$script"
./script4.sh: line 21: 48973 Terminated: 15          "$script"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
parallel -j0 --line-buffer ::: ./script1 ./script2 ./script3
```